# Conversion Failed from converting Date/time from character String

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Okay So I got the problem.
I know there are many questions out there in stackoverflow and I seen alot of them.But the problem is my query is loaded indirectly from DataReader...
I seen similar question but can't understand as it was in ASP.NET with C#

Here is my code below...

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("Select * from FASPRODUCT WHERE FASPRODUCT.Trans_Date between '@ClaimFdt' and '@ClaimTdt'", con1)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("ClaimFdt", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ClaimFdt.value '(even tried .Text Property)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("ClaimTdt", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ClaimTdt.value  '(even tried .Text Property)

    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        Dim dt = New DataTable()
        dt.Load(dr) '----------------- exception caught from here
```

This problem was occured while `ExecuteNonQuery()` in my other code (not here) but some ppl here suggested me to add parameters so I tried again with parameters here..

If there is any other question similar to mine in VB.Net then mark it duplicate and even post the link of the original question, it'll be very helpful..

> Conversion Failed from converting Date/time from character String

Comment: It sounds like `Trans_Date` is stored as text in the db.

Comment: No its date, just checked again and confirmed...@Plutonix

Comment: Have you tried `@ClaimFdt` instead of `'@ClaimFdt'` (removing single quote)?

Comment: I was waiting for you @RezaAghaei, I just try... Glad to see you.. :)

Comment: I even post the error screenshot @Plutonix

Comment: ...remove tick/single quote and *add* the `@`

Comment: @bonny Good to see you too :)  - So include the error message.

Comment: Lol Its done, Quotes are the problem here...
Thanx @RezaAghaei.............
Shall I delete this Question from Stack??? Its just silly mistake and I don't think its needed... What you Say???

Comment: Thanx @Plutonix

Comment: You're welcome :) - Yes, you can see may email at my profile. r.aghaei at outlook.com But you can find me here usually simpler ;)

Comment: Ya okay, Shall I delete this Question>>???? @RezaAghaei

Comment: I don't think you need to delete it. Maybe it helps someone in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Remove Quotes from @ClaimFdt and @ClaimTdt, Credits to **Reza Aghaei**

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("Select * from FASPRODUCT WHERE FASPRODUCT.Trans_Date between @ClaimFdt and @ClaimTdt", con1) '------- Remove Quotes from @ClaimFdt and ClaimTdt
    cmd.Parameters.Add("ClaimFdt", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ClaimFdt.value '(even tried .Text Property)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("ClaimTdt", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ClaimTdt.value  '(even tried .Text Property)

Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    Dim dt = New DataTable()
    dt.Load(dr) '----------------- exception caught from here
```